# TCL: Get a number out of a string using scan

Tags: tcl

I have the following string:

```
  set operating_period          "1.86ns"    ; # set dominant default period , from create_clock command in sdc
```

I would like to get the number out of this. So the result should be
1.86

Any suggestions how to do that in TCL? 
I tried scan, but obviously I fail =( ...

Comment: Nevermind... I did it!

Comment: lindex [split [lindex [split $string \"] 1] ns] 0

Comment: It's pretty nasty, but it works =) !

Answer (score 2):

Use scan:

```
% set operating_period "1.86ns"
1.86ns
% set x [scan $operating_period %f]
1.86
```

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/scan.htm

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm

Comment: Yeah right! But the number is just an example. I want to get an arbitrary number from this position. How to do that?

Comment: It works the same: scan 1ns %f -> 1.0, scan 1.8ns %f -> 1.8
 etc.

Comment: I think you don't understand the problem. If the number is fixed, I don't have to write code to get it... just type it ^^. I'm looking for something like "scan $string %f" and the result is the number inside the string variable. And the string looks like the one above, just the number is not known...

Comment: Your genius formula results in above example "0"... That's because scan does not output the scan result directly, but only the number of hits.

Comment: So in this case, it did not find anything. Unbelievable, right?!

Comment: I don't get your problem. Does $string follow a fixed format? If so you can still use scan, if it doesn't you will have to use regex. If you are just talking about variable input, that is no problem as well: set a "1.8ns"; puts [scan $a %f]; prints 1.8. Edit: regarding you last comment: stop insulting me and read the manual page - "If no varName variables are specified, then scan works in an inline manner, returning the data that would otherwise be stored in the variables as a list."

Comment: Well in my case it doesn't. So maybe I call it wrong? Can you try it with the example above?

Comment: regex {.*?([0-9]*\.[0-9]*ns).*?} "wow yet 183.326ns another float" -> result; puts $result; prints: 183.326ns

Comment: Ok... So that's with regex! It needs a little tweaking from my side, but this would also work. Thank you very much for your help =) !

Comment: @erdin.sinanovic, slyb's example works perfectly well for the sample you gave. I updated the code in a cosmetic way to use your variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when working with particularly ill-formed data (e.g., anything written free-form by people) you have to use a mixture of techniques to extract the data. For example, you can use both `regexp` and `scan`:

```
set inputString "wow yet 183.326ns another float"
if {[scan [regexp -inline {[\d.]+ns} $inputString] "%f" value] == 1} {
    # Found something! It's in $value now
}
```

The `regexp` does the extraction (`-inline` is nice; it makes `regexp` return what it matched) and `scan` “extracts the sense” from what was found and stores a sane floating-point number in `$value`, assuming there was any there in the first place. You might need to tweak the RE to get best results (for example, the current one won't cope with negative numbers right now).